# Java dynamic Map<String, Map> merging to be converted to a JSON

Tags: java, json, collections, hashmap

I'm using a `Map<String, Map> resultMap` having values like this:

```
[
    {main={group={street={cnt=Burundi, zip=123}, code=asd, subtype={OrgType=1,2}}}},
    
    {main={info={text=bbb}}},
    
    {main={group={subId=5, attrib={attribId=1,2}}}}
]
```

I have to create a JSON out of those Maps that should look like this:

```
        { "main": [ 
            { 
               "group": { 
                    "street": {
                         "cnt": "Burundi",
                         "zip": "123"
                    },
                    "code": "asd",
                    "subtype": {
                         "OrgType": "1,2"
                    },
                    "subId": "5",
                    "attribId": "1,2"
                },
                "info": {
                    "text": "bbb"
                }
             }
         ]
      }
```

Any idea how could I merge those Maps doing a `GSON.toJson(resultMap);` to obtain this JSON ?

I tried to merge the Map

```
    public String produceJsonFromMap(Map<String, Map> initialMap) {

         Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

         for(Map map: initialMap.values()) {
              resultMap.putAll(map);
         }
         return GSON.toJson(resultMap);
      }
```

But this overwrites my previous maps and I don't know how can I obtain the desired merged map...

Comment: Gson can't do that for you, **you** have to do that. Parse the 3 input JSON texts using Gson. Merge the 3 maps into a combined map yourself. Use Gson to generate the result JSON text.

Comment: I know Gson can't do that, I was just asking how to merge those n maps into a combined map because I tried and I can't get it merged the way I need...

Comment: Edit the question and show what you tried.

Comment: Why does the result have an array when the inputs don't?